# Undeclared Identifiers in header file with AVR-GCC

Tags: c, gcc, avr

I created the following header file with definitions for AVR pins to be used in my code.

```
#define LED_PORT        PORTB
#define LED_PIN         PINB
#define LED_DDR         DDRB

#define LED0            PB0
```

I encounter two failures I am not able to solve.

1) I have two issues in this header file, shown here:

[image]

2) Also the functions I created in the header file for USART in the USART.h file, I implemented, are not being recognized

[image]

I actually do not understand why that is. As the code clearly has the header file implemented.

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#endif

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "pinDefinition.h"
#include "USART.h"


int main(void) {
  char serialCharacter;
  LED_DDR = 0xff;
  initUSART();
  printString("Hello World!\r\n");

  while (1) {
    serialCharacter = receiveByte();
    transmitByte(serialCharacter);
    LED_PORT = serialCharacter;
  }

  return (0);
}
```

The compiler I am using is AVR-GCC.

Furthermore, when I include the USART.c directly, then everything is working fine. I don't understand why the header file is not working though.

I created a script that runs the compiler/linker:

```
#!/bin/bash
avr-gcc -g -Os -mmcu=atmega328p -c code.c util.c USART.c
avr-gcc -g -mmcu=atmega328p -o code.elf code.o
avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex code.elf code.hex
avr-size --format=avr --mcu=atmega328p code.elf
```

This returns the above mentioned error.

The USART.h looks like this:

```
/* These are defined for convenience */
#define   USART_HAS_DATA   bit_is_set(UCSR0A, RXC0)
#define   USART_READY      bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0)

#include <stdint.h>

void initUSART(void);
void transmitByte(uint8_t data);
uint8_t receiveByte(void);
void printString(const char myString[]);
void readString(char myString[], uint8_t maxLength);
void printByte(uint8_t byte);
void printWord(uint16_t word);
void printBinaryByte(uint8_t byte);
char nibbleToHex(uint8_t nibble);
char nibbleToHexCharacter(uint8_t nibble);
void printHexByte(uint8_t byte);
uint8_t getNumber(void);
```

I really require some help as I am trying to solve this now for three days and read a lot of different sources (I am getting my ropes together still with C so please be mindful).C

Comment: Where are `PORTB` and `DDRB` defined?

Comment: PORTB and DDRB are part of avr/io.h I would assume

Comment: Header files typically provide declarations, not definitions. Definitions are typically in source files.

Comment: I took this from ```https://github.com/hexagon5un/AVR-Programming/blob/master/AVR-Programming-Library/pinDefines.h```

Comment: I especially do not understand why the USART functions are not found

Comment: You never do anything with `util.o` or `USART.o`.

Comment: the variables are defined in '#include <avr/io.h>'

Comment: @melpomene that is the reason!! Now it compiled... oh gosh...

Comment: @jxh but for some reason even after now compiling and linking correctly, my editor complains about the variables which are defined

Comment: So, they were defined in `USART.c`.

Comment: @jxh actually not. just in the header file

Comment: If they remained undefined until you added `util.o` and `USART.o`, then they were defined in one of the source files associated with those objects.

Answer (score 0):

> I created a script that runs the compiler/linker:
> `avr-gcc -g -Os -mmcu=atmega328p -c code.c util.c USART.c`

This command generates **three** files: `code.o`, `util.o` and `USART.o`, whereas the following link command only links one object file:

> `avr-gcc -g -mmcu=atmega328p -o code.elf code.o`

Hence, all functions from the latter two compilation units are missing, which leads tu bunch of *"undefined reference to"* from the linker.  Fix is to link all three object files:

`avr-gcc -g -mmcu=atmega328p -o code.elf code.o util.o USART.o`

---

> Undeclared Identifiers in header file

A header file (`module.h`) in C just contains declarations of functions in the module (`module.c`), but the implementation / definition of the functions is in the *.c file.
(One exception are `static inline` functions which are defined in the header, but this is not the case for the undefined references from your code.)